# What are "intervals" in swift ranges?

Tags: swift

I know there are 3 types of ranges: Range, Strides and Intervals.

```
var closed:ClosedInterval = 1.2...5.0

var half_open:HalfOpenInterval = 1.2..<5.0
```

What are intervals in swift? and what is one example of their use?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)

EDIT: 
This is what the beta 5 xcode 6 release notes says:

• Intervals over Comparable values, which can efficiently check for containment. Intervals are 
used for pattern matching in switch statements and by the ~= operator.

Comment: Isn't that in the book?

Comment: Not in the book that I can see. only in the beta 5 release notes. "• Intervals over Comparable values, which can efficiently check for containment. Intervals are 
used for pattern matching in switch statements and by the ~= operator."

Comment: I can't find discussions of ranges, intervals or strides in any of the Apple docs. They may be in there, but they ain't easy to find. The Apple online docs are extremely hard to search, and they pulled the PDF version of the language ref. Like a lot of things Swift, I need to grope around with a playground to figure this out.

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1023560#1023560

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Swift 3 (with Xcode 8), the `Interval` types are no more. Now the family of `Range<T>` types include the functionality of both the former range and interval types, and additionally conform to the [new model for collection types and indices](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/1116f49cba960762be9e77af026d3e41e3cef0d7/proposals/0065-collections-move-indices.md).

---

In Swift 2.x and older... Ranges are for iterating, and Intervals are for pattern matching.

```
func testNum(num: Int) {
    let interval: HalfOpenInterval = 0..<10
    let range = 10..<20
    switch num {
    case interval:    // this works
        break
    case range:       // error "does not conform to protocol IntervalType"
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

A `Range` type is optimized for generating values that increment through the range, and works with types that can be counted and incremented.

An `Interval` type is optimized for testing whether a given value lies within the interval.  It works with types that don't necessarily need a notion of incrementing, and provides operations like clamping one range to another (e.g. `(0..<10).clamp(5..<15)` yields `5..<10`) that are useful for complex pattern matching.

Because the `..<` and `...` operators have two forms each--one that returns a `Range` and one that returns an `Interval`--type inference automatically uses the right one based on context. So, if you write `0..<10` in a `case` label of a `switch` statement, Swift automatically constructs a `HalfOpenInterval` because a `switch` statement requires an `Interval` type.

The `~=` operator is a way to do one test on an interval without a `switch` statement. Writing `interval ~= value` is equivalent to `interval.contains(value)`.

---

It's worth noting that you can find out many of these things by looking at the standard library interface and its comments: write a type name like `HalfOpenInterval` in a playground, then command-click to jump to its definition.

Comment: Cool. Thank you. Now I also know what clamp does! ;) I get it. More like a range that can not be iterated as in decimal but the in between values can be checked with interval.contains(value). Thank you

Answer (score 35):

I figured this is as good a place as any to leave this work.

***UPDATE:*** [I have redone this in my "Swiftwater" series (Link to the series entry on my Web site).](https://littlegreenviper.com/series/swiftwater/ranges-and-sequences/)

Since Apple has done such an awful job of describing Ranges and Intervals, I am working through them in a big fat playground (That's how I do this stuff). I figured I'd leave the playground here in sections.

This is also a great way to get corrections and peer review, as I'd much rather understand things and do them properly, than be some kind of "nerd god." I frequently get things wrong, and make bad assumptions. Peer review is great for that.

Also, I consider this a public service, as there are few things geeks like more than telling other geeks they are wrong. No, don't thank me. I'll get my reward in Heaven.

In any case, here is the playground for today. It is all about specifying them. In following days, I'll just paste in the subsequent portions of the playground.

Note the string Intervals. I'm going to be messing around with them a bit later.

I will also try creating classes that can be incremented, and see if they can be used as Range values.

**UPDATE:** *I have now gone through basic usage. It appears as if multi-character string intervals are in an undefined area. I'll raise a RADAR issue on it, and see what Apple has to say.*

**UPDATE<sup>2</sup>:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25711756/879365) covers the String Interval oddness.

**UPDATE<sup>3</sup>:** I updated it for Swift 3.

**UPDATE<sup>4</sup>:** I updated it for Swift 4. I still need to do more testing, but I think this is OK.

You should open the Assistant Editor (Console), so you can see the results of all the print() statements (they don't always display in the gutter for loops).

```
// PART 1: SPECIFYING RANGES AND INTERVALS
// 1.1: RANGES

// First, we look at the Range type. Ranges are designed for incrementing. They have to be scalar (incrementable, usually, integers).
// Ranges always represent internally as min..<max When you do an inclusive range, it will represent internally as min..<max+1
let range1:CountableRange<Int>          = 0..<10    /* This contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 */
let range2:CountableRange               = 0..<10    /* This also contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 */
let range3                              = 0..<10    /* This also contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 */
let range4:CountableClosedRange<Int>    = 0...9     /* This also contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 */
let range5:CountableClosedRange         = 0...9     /* This also contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 */
let range6                              = 0...9     /* This also contains 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 */
// let range7:Range<Float>             = 0..<10    /* This is an error. Floats can't be incremented. */
// let range8:Range                    = 0.0...9.0 /* This is also an error. */
// let range9:Range<String>            = "0"..."9" /* This is an error. Even though these are strings in sequence, they can't be incremented. */

// 1.2: INTERVALS

// Next, let's look at the Interval type. Intervals represent spreads of values, and can be non-integer types.

// 1.2.1: TYPES OF INTERVALS

// 1.2.1.1: CLOSED

// Closed intervals
let closed1:ClosedRange<Int>                     = 1...5         /* This represents 1,2,3,4,5 */
let closed2:ClosedRange                          = 3...7         /* This represents 3,4,5,6,7 */
// let closed3:ClosedInterval                          = 3..<8         /* This is an error. You can't specify a closed interval with an open operator. */

let closed4                                         = 3...7         /* This is not an Interval. It is a Range. */
let closed5                                         = 3..<8         /* This is not an Interval. It is a Range. */

let closed6Float:ClosedRange<Float>              = 2...9         /* This represents 2.0 -> 9.0 as a continuous range. */
let closed7Double                                   = 2.0...9.0     /* This represents 2.0 -> 9.0 as a continuous range. Specifying as a Double makes it an Interval.  */

// String Intervals
// These are odd. Looks like it is using the ASCII values. I should experiment with Unicode, and see where we go...
let aThroughFClosed:ClosedRange<String>          = "A"..."F"
let dThroughQClosed:ClosedRange                  = "D"..."Q"
let mThroughSClosed:ClosedRange                  = "M"..."S"
let tThroughWClosed:ClosedRange                  = "T"..."W"
let whiskeyTangoFoxtrot1                            = "QED"..."WTF" /* Not sure what will happen when I start working with this... */

// 1.2.1.2: HALF-OPEN

// Half-open intervals can only be open in the last value. The first value is inclusive.
let afopen1:Range<Int>                   = 5..<10        /* This represents 5,6,7,8,9 */
let afopen2:Range<Int>                   = 7..<20        /* This represents 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 */
let afopenFloat1:Range<Float>            = 2..<9         /* This represents 2.0 < 9.0 as a continuous range. */
let afopenFloat2:Range<Float>            = 7..<13        /* This represents 7.0 < 13.0 as a continuous range. */
// let afopen3:HalfOpenInterval<Int>                   = 5>..10        /* This is an error. You can't have half-open intervals open on the bottom. */
// let afopenFloat3:HalfOpenInterval<Float>            = 2...9         /* This is an error. You can't specify a half open as a closed. */

let aThroughHHalfOpen:Range<String>      = "A"..<"H"
let dThroughRHalfOpen:Range              = "D"..<"R"
let mThroughTHalfOpen:Range              = "M"..<"T"
let tThroughXHalfOpen:Range              = "T"..<"X"
let whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2                            = "QED"..<"WTF"

// 1.2.2: CLAMPING

// Clamping is basically the same as a set intersect. It selects the highest low value as the start, and the lowest high value as the end.
// You can clamp intervals, but not ranges.
let clampedValue1                                   = closed2.clamped ( to: closed1 )     /* This represents 3,4,5 */
let clampedValue2                                   = afopen2.clamped ( to: afopen1 )     /* This represents 7,8,9 */
// let clampedValue3                                   = closed2.clamped ( to: afopen1 )  /* This is an error. You can't mix interval types. */
// let clampedValue4                                   = afopenFloat2.clamped ( to: afopen1 )   /* This is an error. You can't clamp mixed types. */
// let clampedValue5                                   = closed4.clamped ( to: closed1 )  /* This is an error. Ranges can't clamp. */

let clampedString1 = dThroughQClosed.clamped ( to: aThroughFClosed )  /* This represents "D"..."F" */
let clampedString2 = aThroughFClosed.clamped ( to: dThroughQClosed )  /* This represents "D"..."F" */
let clampedString3 = mThroughSClosed.clamped ( to: dThroughQClosed )  /* This represents "M"..."Q" */
let clampedString4 = tThroughWClosed.clamped ( to: dThroughQClosed )  /* This represents "Q"..."Q" */
let clampedString5 = tThroughWClosed.clamped ( to: aThroughFClosed )  /* This represents "F"..."F" */

let clampedString6 = dThroughRHalfOpen.clamped ( to: aThroughHHalfOpen )  /* This represents "D"..<"G" */
let clampedString7 = aThroughHHalfOpen.clamped ( to: dThroughRHalfOpen )  /* This represents "D"..<"H" */
let clampedString8 = mThroughTHalfOpen.clamped ( to: dThroughRHalfOpen )  /* This represents "M"..<"R" */
let clampedString9 = tThroughXHalfOpen.clamped ( to: dThroughRHalfOpen )  /* This represents "R"..<"R" */
let clampedString0 = tThroughXHalfOpen.clamped ( to: aThroughHHalfOpen )  /* This represents "H"..<"H" (Not exactly sure why) */

// PART 2: USING RANGES AND INTERVALS

// 2.1 USING RANGES

// 2.1.1 RANGES AS LOOP ITERATORS

// The main use for ranges is cheap iterators for loops. They are easy to specify, and easy to use.

// A standard iterator
for i in range1 { print ( "Loop Iteration \(i)" ) }

// You can use the wildcard if you don't care about the actual iterator value.
for _ in range1 { print ( "Another Loop Iteration." ) }

// 2.2: USING INTERVALS

// Intervals are used for purposes of comparison and value matching.

// 2.2.1: INTEGER INTERVALS

// This is an error. You can't iterate Intervals.
// for i in closed1 { print ( "Loop Iteration \(i)" ) }

// 2.2.1.1 INTEGER INTERVALS AS SWITCH TESTS

// Use Intervals in switch statements to specify a range of possible values (a "catchbasket").
var testValue1 = 1

switch ( testValue1 )
{
    // This is an error. You can't match against Ranges.
    //    case closed4:
    //        print ( "In range!" )
    // This is an error. The Interval is a Double, but the test is an Int.
    //    case closed7Double:
    //        print ( "In closed7Double" )

case closed1:
    print ( "In closed1." )   /* This will catch the value. */

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

switch ( testValue1 )   /* This will test against the interval of 3 -> 5 */
{
case clampedValue1:
    print ( "In clampedValue1." )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )  /* Since it is not in the clamped interval, we fall into the catchall. */
}

// We try it with 3 as the value.
testValue1 = 3

switch ( testValue1 )
{
case closed1:
    print ( "In closed1." )   /* This will catch the value again. */

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

switch ( testValue1 )
{
case clampedValue1:
    print ( "In clampedValue1." )   /* Now that the test value is in the interval window, we catch it here. */

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// This is a logical error (but not flagged by the compiler, so it counts as a "gotcha"). The two intervals have overlapping ranges.
// You are allowed to specify intervals that overlap, but only the first "hit" will count.

switch ( testValue1 )
{
case closed1:   /* This will catch all numbers between 1 and 5. */
    print ( "In closed1." )   /* This will catch the value, even though it also falls into the next one. */

case clampedValue1: /* This will not catch any numbers, as the interval is 3,4,5. */
    print ( "In clampedValue1." )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// If we switch the two tests, then the clampedValue1 test is the hit.

switch ( testValue1 )
{
case clampedValue1:
    print ( "In clampedValue1." )   /* This will catch the value, even though it also falls into the next one. */

case closed1:
    print ( "In closed1." )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// However, in this one, the second test will hit, because 1 is not in the first interval.
testValue1 = 1

switch ( testValue1 )
{
case clampedValue1:
    print ( "In clampedValue1." )

case closed1:
    print ( "In closed1." )   /* You sunk my battleship! */

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// 2.2.1.2 INTEGER INTERVALS AS BOOLEAN TESTS

// You test by using the Interval.contains() method.

if ( closed1.contains ( testValue1 ) )
{
    print ( "We gots us a match!" )
}

if ( !clampedValue1.contains ( testValue1 ) )
{
    print ( "We gots us a mismatch!" )
}

// 2.2.2: FLOATING POINT INTERVALS

// 2.2.2.1: FLOATING POINT INTERVALS AS SWITCH TESTS

var testValue2:Float = 2.0

switch ( testValue2 )
{
    // This is an error. You can't compare against other types.
    //    case closed1:
    //        print ( "In closed1." )

case afopenFloat1:  /* This will catch the value, as it is within the interval range. */
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case afopenFloat2:
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue2 = 7.0

switch ( testValue2 )
{
case afopenFloat1: /* This will catch it, even though it is also in the next test range. */
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case afopenFloat2:
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue2 = 8.999999   /* NOTE: Look at the displayed value. */

switch ( testValue2 )
{
case afopenFloat1: /* This will catch it. */
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case afopenFloat2:
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// This illustrates a precision "gotcha." Note what happens when we add one more "9" to the end.
testValue2 = 8.9999999

switch ( testValue2 )
{
case afopenFloat1:
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case afopenFloat2: /* This will catch it, even though the number is "less" than 9.0. */
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue2 = 9.0

switch ( testValue2 )
{
case afopenFloat1: /* This will not catch it, as the value needs to be LESS than 9.0 to match. */
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case closed6Float:
    print ( "In the range of 2...9!" )  /* This will catch the value, as it is within the closed interval range. */

case afopenFloat2:
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue2 = 9.00001

switch ( testValue2 )
{
    // This is an error. The Interval is a ClosedInterval<Double>, but the test value is a Float
    //    case closed7Double:
    //        print ( "In closed7Double" )

case afopenFloat1: /* This will not catch it, as the value needs to be LESS than 9.0 to match. */
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case closed6Float:
    print ( "In the range of 2...9!" )

case afopenFloat2:
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" ) /* This will catch the value, as it is within the interval range. */

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue2 = 1.0

switch ( testValue2 )
{
case afopenFloat1:
    print ( "In the range of 2..<9!" )

case afopenFloat2:
    print ( "In the range of 7..<13!" )

default: /* Since neither of the above intervals has this value, we get it. */
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// Test with a Double (not a Float).
var testValue2Double:Double = 2.0

switch ( testValue2Double )
{
case closed7Double:  /* This will catch it. */
    print ( "In closed7Double" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue2Double = 1.999999999999999    /* There is enough precision to make this just less than 2.0 */

switch ( testValue2Double )
{
case closed7Double:
    print ( "In closed7Double" )

default:  /* This will catch it. */
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// 2.2.2.2 FLOATING POINT INTERVALS AS BOOLEAN TESTS

testValue2 = 2.345

if ( afopenFloat1.contains ( testValue2 ) )
{
    print ( "We gots us a match!" )
}

if ( !afopenFloat2.contains ( testValue2 ) )
{
    print ( "We gots us a mismatch!" )
}

// 2.2.3: STRING INTERVALS

// String intervals are weird. Just sayin'...

// 2.2.3.1: STRING INTERVALS AS SWITCH TESTS

var testValue3:String = "B"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case aThroughFClosed:   /* This will catch it. */
    print ( "In A...F." )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// Looks like the test is only on the first letter.
testValue3 = "Badz-Maru"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case aThroughFClosed:   /* This will catch it. */
    print ( "In A...F." )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "\tBadz-Maru"   /* If we add a tab character to the start of the string, then the first test will fail. */

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case aThroughFClosed:
    print ( "In A...F." )

default:    /* This will catch it. */
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// Now, we'll get really strange. Let's look at our multi-character intervals...

testValue3 = "W"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:  /* This catches it. */
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "T"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:  /* This catches it. */
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "F"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default: /* However, in this case, it falls through to default. */
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "WT"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2: /* "WT" is caught. */
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "WTF"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:    /* "WTF" is not caught. */
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "QED"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:  /* "QED" is caught. */
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "QTF"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:  /* "QTF" is caught. */
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "QSF"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:  /* "QSF" is caught. */
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default:
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

testValue3 = "QAF"

switch ( testValue3 )
{
case whiskeyTangoFoxtrot2:
    print ( "WTF, dude?" )

default: /* QAF falls through. */
    print ( "In catchall." )
}

// Basically, I don't think we should use multi-character strings in intervals. The behavior seems undefined.

// PART 3: STRIDES

// Strides are sort of a Range. They are mostly used to iterate for loops. Use a stride to iterate in "jumps," or to iterate backwards (Ranges cannot be defined in reverse).

let randallFlagg:StrideTo<Int> = stride ( from: 0, to: 6, by: 3 )   /* StrideTo is a "half open" Range. It does not include the last value. */

for i1 in randallFlagg
{
    print ( "i1 is \(i1)" )
}

let aragorn:StrideThrough<Int> = stride ( from: 0, through: 6, by: 3 )  /* StrideThrough is a "closed" Range, which includes the last value. */

for i2 in aragorn
{
    print ( "i2 is \(i2)" )
}

// We can also use Strides to iterate backwards.

let frodo:StrideThrough<Int> = stride ( from: 6, through: 0, by: -3 )

for i3 in frodo
{
    print ( "i3 is \(i3)" )
}

// You can implicitly type the strides.
let bubbaThrough = stride ( from: 1, through: 5, by: 1 )

for bub in bubbaThrough
{
    print( "Bubba be \(bub)" )
}

let bubbaTo = stride ( from: 0, to: 5, by: 2 )

for bub in bubbaTo
{
    print( "Bubba be \(bub)" )
}

// Strides are often defined directly in the loop declarations.

for bub in stride ( from: 6, through: 0, by: -2 )
{
    print( "Bubba be \(bub)" )
}

// You can define a nonsensical stride, but it won't result in any loop executions.
let bubbaBad = stride ( from: 0, to: 5, by: -2 )

for bub in bubbaBad
{
    print( "Bubba be bad: \(bub)" )
}

// One advantage of Strides, is that you can increment in floating point steps.
let strideFloat:StrideTo<Float> = stride ( from: Float(0), to: 5, by: 2.1 )

for i4 in strideFloat
{
    print( "i4 is \(i4)" )
}

// These are the basics of the Range, Interval and Stride types, but there's a lot more depth to this rabbit hole...

// PART 4: Range Generators (SequenceType)

// Range generators are basically iterators. Iterable classes can spit out a generator, which is basically a disposable iterator.

// This example came from here: http://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/playing-with-swift/

let arr = [1, 2, 3]

for x in arr
{
    print ( x )
}

// Which is really...

var arrGen = arr.makeIterator()

while let x = arrGen.next()
{
    print ( x )
}

// Try the same thing with a dictionary.

let uncleBobIsCool = [ "A":1, "B":2, "C":3, "D":4, "E":5 ]

for x in uncleBobIsCool
{
    print ( x )
}

var dictGen = uncleBobIsCool.makeIterator()

while let x = dictGen.next()
{
    print ( x )
}

// This is an example I plucked from here: http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/08/swift-adopt-sequence-protocol-and-use.html

// This shows how to create a simple struct-based iterator.

// SequenceType is a struct (not a class), and requires a GeneratorType-based struct as a typealias
struct MySequence:Sequence
{
    var x, y, length:Int    // These are the hypothetical struct data members.

    // The SequenceType protocol dictates that we have a generate() method that emits a GeneratorType-based struct.
    // Swift is kinda cool, in that you can define a typealias as a required prototype component.
    typealias GeneratorType = MyGenerator

    // This function instantiates a generator object, and returns that.
    // Since this is a struct, the object is a struct, and is returned by value.
    // That means that this object will not be affected by the iterator.
    func makeIterator() -> GeneratorType
    {
        // Length indicates how many iterations will be allowed.
        // The other two parameters are the starting values of the data members.
        return MyGenerator ( x:x, y:y, length:length )
    }

    mutating func next() -> GeneratorType.Element? {
        if length == 0 {
            return nil
        } else {
            length -= 1
            x += 1
            y += 1
            return ( x, y )
        }
    }
}

// This struct models one generator object.
// The generator is a "disposable" instance that is created by an instance of MySequence.
// The GeneratorType protocol requires a generic type, called "Element," which can be anything you want,
// and a "next()" method that returns one of the "Element" instances.
struct MyGenerator:IteratorProtocol
{
    var x, y, length:Int    // These are the values

    typealias Element = ( Int, Int )    // In the case of this example, "Element" is a tuple, containing x and y Int values.

    // This is the required next() method. Since this is a struct, we need the "mutating" keyword.
    mutating func next() -> Element?    // The return is optional, as we return nil when done.
    {
        // We just go for as many counts as "length" gave us, incrementing the values as we go.
        if length > 0
        {
            length -= 1
            x += 1
            y += 1
            return ( x, y )
        }
        else
        {
            return nil  // At the end, we return nil.
        }
    }
}

var seq = MySequence ( x:10, y:10, length:10 )

for point in seq
{
    print ( point )
}

// We can go again without a rewind.
// Note the data member values are at the old starting point.
// That's because internally, a new generator is created.

for point in seq
{
    print ( point )
}

// Let's create a new instance.
seq = MySequence ( x:10, y:10, length:10 )

// This is what's going on inside.
// Note that we need a "var", as we are mutating the struct.
var seqGen = seq.makeIterator()

// Since we generated a new generator, we start from the beginning again.
while let x = seqGen.next()
{
    print ( x )
}

// Now, if we try to go again, we won't have any luck.
while let x = seqGen.next()
{
    print ( x )
}

// However, if we reset length in the generator, we can go again, continuing to increment the values.
seqGen.length = 10

while let x = seqGen.next()
{
    print ( x )
}

// Just to prove that the original instance remains untouched.
print ( "x: \( seq.x ), y: \( seq.y ), length: \( seq.length )" )
```

That's it for the now. I'll be looking at some of the more advanced behaviors of this stuff on my own, but I figgered I'd put this playground up here in an effort to improve the tribal knowledge on this stuff.

I'm really hoping that Apple improves their docs on this, thus, obviating my answer.

Comment: Interested in why the downvote? Is the playground wrong? If so, I would be most grateful for a correction. Thanks!

Comment: I did find one error (I treated a half-open interval as a closed one). That's fixed. Any other issues? Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: Very impressive work! I think you covered just about every possible case anyone could ever think of. Does this still produce the same output in Swift 1.2?

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tried that, yet. I'm pretty much tied to shipping Xcode for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Happy to report that your code works just fine in Xcode 6.3 (latest mid-Feb 2015)!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I just downloaded 6.3, but it will be a while before I can test with it. I tried to hit all the "what if..." questions I have when doing this stuff.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks so much!

Comment: I am in the process of converting this to Swift 3. I won't release it until Xcode 8 is officially out.