# Range shenanigans

Tags: ios, swift, range

Okay, I looked at the suggestions above, and none of them quite hit the mark.

The issue I am having is with the Range primitive/class/collection whatzit in Swift.

Ranges are cool.

And badly documented (**NOTE:** Just because *"It's in the manual"* does NOT mean it's *"well documented."* If I can't easily find it -which I can't-, then that means it isn't actually well-documented. Indexes and ToCs are **VERY IMPORTANT**).

I certainly appreciate being directed towards the relevant sections of the documentation.

Now, what I REALLY want, is the ability to treat ranges like sets, with intersections and unions, and whatnot.

Failing that, I decided that I'd like to roll my own.

I'll paste my playground below. It's pretty simple.

First of all, in the app I'm writing now, I'd like to use a range to describe a range of relevant indexes, with a starting index and an ending index.

That means a `Range<Int>`.

What I discovered, is that all `Range<Int>` ranges are stored as start:Int..<end:Int, even if you specify them as start:Int...end:Int.

That makes getting the last value a bit tricky. If you ask for Range.endIndex, you get end:Int + 1.

Now, if you look at my union sample below, you will see that the final range delivers an endIndex of 21.

I have a feeling that I'm using ranges all wrong.

```
let rangeA:Range<Int> = 3...7

var low:Int = rangeA.startIndex // This is 3
var high:Int = rangeA.endIndex  // This is 8

let rangeB:Range<Int> = 1...9

let rangeC:Range<Int> = 7...19

var lowestValue:Int = min ( rangeA.startIndex, rangeA.endIndex )

lowestValue = min ( lowestValue, min ( rangeB.startIndex, rangeB.endIndex ) )

lowestValue = min ( lowestValue, min ( rangeC.startIndex, rangeC.endIndex ) )

var highestValue = max ( rangeA.startIndex, rangeA.endIndex )

highestValue = max ( highestValue, max ( rangeB.startIndex, rangeB.endIndex ) )

highestValue = max ( highestValue, max ( rangeC.startIndex, rangeC.endIndex ) )

let unityRange:Range<Int> = lowestValue...highestValue

low = unityRange.startIndex // This is 1
high = unityRange.endIndex  // This is 21
```

Comment: Where is your problem? The `endIndex` (which is - as you already noticed - one past the last range value) for A, B, C is 8, 10, 20, resp., with a maximum of 20. Thus `unityRange = 1 ... 20` has an endIndex of 21. Perhaps you wanted `unityRange = lowestValue ..< highestValue` ?

Comment: It is also stated in the release notes (if I remember correctly) that the start index *must not* be greater than the end index for ranges, which makes some of your min/max calculations obsolete.

Comment: Sounds like you want an `NSIndexSet`

Comment: You are correct. I just figured out why I got 21. -Duh. The operation is a generic one. You're right. No need for some of that stuff. It would be great if we had set operators for ranges, but I guess that would be too complex.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using NS sets. I am looking at the advantages of native Swift, and seeing if I can leverage it.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that ranges are not the same as sets in important ways. In particular, for sets, |A+B| ≤ |A|+|B|, but for ranges (the way you're doing it), |A+B| is unbounded. It doesn't mean that what you're doing doesn't make sense; it's just that it isn't a set. And the way you're doing it isn't like an `NSIndexSet` either (again, because you're filling in any gaps).

Comment: Yes, one question is what the union of `1...3` and `7...8` should be. - And note that there are also *intervals*, which are similar to ranges, but not restricted to discrete types, i.e. an interval of the floating point numbers 1.2 ... 3.4 .

Comment: Sounds like what you're really after is not a range, but an interval. Those are made for testing; `Range` is made for iterating. Check `ClosedInterval` and `HalfOpenInterval` in the standard library "header", and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308978/what-are-intervals-in-swift-ranges/25314936#25314936).

Comment: Ask a question, don't tell us a story. I stopped reading after your 4th sentence.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Glad to hear feedback from other folks that ask lots of questions.

Comment: You know, I gave this some thought over the weekend. @Marián Černý, that was unwise. I'm a senior development manager in my day job. I hire folks like you. I suspect there are many more like myself. This is especially true for companies like Google and Apple, where managers often retain technical duties even far up the food chain (I ain't that far up). This isn't /b/. We should consider what we say and do here to be on our permanent record.