# Pattern match in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pattern-matching

Im checking if a value is within a range like this:

```
if 0..<10 ~= aValue {
    // Code
}
```

But when I try to do it like this:

```
let range = anEnum == .VALUE ? 0..<10 : 10..<20
if range ~= aValue {
    // Code
}
```

Its telling me: `Type 'Range<Int>' does not conform to protocol 'IntervalType'`

Isnt this: `0..<10` and this: `let range = 10..<20` the exact same thing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308978/what-are-intervals-in-swift-ranges

Comment: Thanks man, didnt know what to search for